# Cannot get session values in middleware nuxt

Tags: javascript, session, middleware, nuxt.js, adonis.js

i'm trying to implement an auth middleware in nuxt.js, using adonisjs as backend server.

My auth middlware is like this:

```
export default async function (ctx) {
    response = await axios.get('http://192.168.56.2/test-login', {withCredentials: true})
    console.log(response.data.code)
    // code should be 0 if user is logged, and 1 if not logged
}
```

But everytime i load the page, the code is always 0, and in my backend server the session object is empty.

Instead, if i run the same code in `mounted` function, i get the code 1 and the session object in the backend server has the session information.

So it's like i cannot get the session object during server side render.

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: obviously because request executes on server.So it dont have any session data. All this data is on client. You need to use something like jwt auth

Comment: I don't understand, why shouldn't be any session data, since i'm simply making an http request to my backend server using credentials?  The request is made by the client(nuxt) to the server(adonis), therefore the session data is on the backend server. 
Could you explain better?

Comment: using what credentials? You are making http request from a nuxt server, from node. I mean your backend server do some check to distinguish between auth and not auth user. Node server wont send any credentaisl that would be sent from user e.g. cookies and such things

Comment: My backend code check if there a `sessionId` field in the current session and retrieve the corresponding user, then send back the logged user. In my case, the sessionId is retrieved only during the mounted call, and not during the middleware request. The enpoint `http://192.168.56.2/test-login` does not need to check if the user is logged or not, it only reply with logged user.
When i said `withCredentials` i meant that in my http request i set the `withCredentials` field to avoid cors.

Comment: And session id is stored where? IN cookies, right?. And cookies where? On client, but not on nuxt server side. And withCredentials dont do anything since the request are made on node. CORS only applicable to client

Comment: Ok, now i get it. Thank you

Comment: take a look at nuxt auth module https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module